# One to Many relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables `users` `companies` `company_users` when I try to get user company details it return null

#### Logic

1. company has many users
2. user belong to 1 company

`user model`

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_users', 'user_id', 'company_id');
}
```

`company model`

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'company_users', 'company_id', 'user_id');
}
```

[image: one]

any idea?

Comment: If its a one to many relation then you don't need that pivot table and instead add company_id in users table

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid you're right I should do that.

Comment: so why are you creating this company_users table just pass the companies foreign key in  users table. and your relation work perfect.

Comment: @Shahrukh yes I've changed my database now.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid If you share an answer I'll accept that.

Comment: Azahar Alam already answered it :), Next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770996/one-to-many-relation-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment116286992_65770996):

If you really want one to many relation. Try this:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

Comment: these relationships are wrong ... but what ever

Comment: can you please correct me where I was wrong?

Answer (score 2):

it's not one to many relation it's [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), with pivot table (company_users )

so, the relation should be like:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'company_users', 'user_id', 'company_id');
}
```

I recommend rename it to 'companies' cause it plural

Comment: user has 1 company only, its not many to many. in other hand company has many users